# next js dynamic page routing working in localhost but giving file not found error in production

Tags: next.js, vercel, dynamic-routing

This is part of my next js project. This website is running perfectly on localhost but when i deploy it on vercel, the /blogs/book/chapter page is giving me file not found enter image description here500 error.

Hosted Page - [Website](https://manav.vercel.app/blog)
Source Code - [GitHub](https://github.com/manavgoyal111/manav)

### Dynamic Routing Folder Structure

[Page Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsvkG.jpg)

### chapter.js

```js
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import Head from "next/head";
import DefaultErrorPage from "next/error";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import { marked } from "marked";
import styles from "../../../../styles/blog/Chapter.module.css";
import { capitalise } from "../../../../components/blog/Capitalise";
import BlogPostBottom from "../../../../components/blog/BlogPostBottom";

export default function Chapter({ book, chapter, frontmatter, content }) {
    // Destructuring
    const { description } = frontmatter;

    // Router Variable
    const router = useRouter();

    // If fallback then show this
    if (router.isFallback) {
        // if (router.isFallback || !book || !chapter || !content) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!book || !chapter || !content || !frontmatter) {
        return (
            <div>
                <DefaultErrorPage statusCode={404} />
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.bookChapter}>
            <Head>
                <title>{`${capitalise(chapter)} | ${capitalise(
                    book
                )} | Blog | Manav Goyal`}</title>
                <meta
                    name="description"
                    content={`Read Blog about this book ${book} covering chapter ${chapter} of topics ${description}`}
                />
            </Head>

            <h1>{`${capitalise(chapter)} - ${capitalise(book)}`}</h1>

            <section
                className={styles.bookChapterContent}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(content) }}
            ></section>

            <BlogPostBottom slug={`/blog/${book}`} />
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [{ params: { book: "css", chapter: "bootstrap" } }],
        // paths: [],
        fallback: true,
    };
}

// Web crawlers, won't be served a fallback and instead the path will behave as in fallback: 'blocking'
// fallback: true is not supported when using `next export`
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const { book, chapter } = params;

    let chapterPost = null;
    try {
        chapterPost = await fs.promises.readFile(
            path.join(`posts/${book}/${chapter}.md`),
            "utf-8"
        );
    } catch (err) {}

    const { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(chapterPost);

    return {
        props: {
            book,
            chapter,
            frontmatter,
            content,
        },
        // redirect: {
        //  destination: `/blog/${book}`,
        //  permanent: false,
        // },
        // revalidate: 1,
    };
}

Chapter.defaultProps = {
    book: "css",
    chapter: "bootstrap",
    frontmatter: { description: "CSS", id: "1" },
    content: "Error",
};
```

### Posts Folder Structure

[Posts Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo523.jpg)

### Error

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFbTb.jpg)

[Vercel Function Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTRWu.jpg)

Comment: You should probably use `process.cwd` to construct the file path that you want to read, e.g. ``path.join(process.cwd(), `posts/${book}/${chapter}.md`)``. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#reading-files-use-processcwd.